# Thumbnail only appears in Facebook Share dialog after refreshing the page

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I've added a FB share button to a page on my site, using this method: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/share-links/

Source code looks like this:

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?
    u=https://[subdomain].mysmilecentral.com/public/show?link_code=[access code for individual's photo]" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://[our S3 bucket]/images/fb-share-btn2.png" style="margin-top: -35px; margin-right: 126px; float: right" />
</a>
```

I've got the `FB Javascript SDK` loading asynchronously, and am using `OG` meta tags:

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="https://[subdomain].mysmilecentral.com/public/show?link_code=[access code for individual's photo]" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Order Pictures of [child's name] at [studio name]'s MySmileCentral!" />
<meta property="og:description" content="View images and/or order pictures of [child's name]." />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://[our S3 bucket]/[path to JPEG image]" />
```

Facebook's Object Debugger finds everything without a problem.

However,  the Share Dialog doesn't show the thumbnail image defined in my *`og:image`* tag until I refresh the page.  Every subsequent time that image is shared the thumbnail properly displays without needing a page-refresh.

What's the issue here?

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache before sharing the page? and tried to load the SDK synchronously?

Comment: I assume you mean clear the cache Facebook has for the page, by debugging in with the Object Debugger.  No, I have not.  I don't see how Facebook could even have the page cached in the first place when it's the first time the page has been shared.  Also curious how loading the SDK synchronously could have an effect.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Agree you don't need to load the SDK synchronously because it doesn't impact meta tags. I meant refresh your browser cache. If it works when you press F5 it is not a problem with Facebook internal caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone revisiting this issue, as of approximately Nov. 11, 2014, Facebook has provided a better solution than previously mentioned.  According to [this FB bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/657696104321030/):

> If your site provides both og:image, og:image:width and
>   og:image:height, that image *will* be used even for the first share
>   created. Failing to provide these means that you will need to wait for
>   our crawlers to fetch and analyze the images first.
>
> See http://ogp.me/#structured for an example of how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm that your image is valid:

> og:image – This is an image associated with your media. We suggest that you use an image of at least 200x200 pixels. However, bigger is better, so if you have a 1500x1500 image that you can use, please use it. We'll downsample and crop it for for people using smaller-resolution devices but will use it on a larger device. The larger this image is, the more likely it will be used when sharing stories on Facebook. (Note: image sizes must be no more than 5MB in size.)

From [Facebook: Maximizing Distribution for Media Content](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/)

**EDIT:**

Clear the cache of your browser.

Comment: The image is valid, yes.  The browser cache was the problem.  Make that your answer and I'll up-vote it for you.  :)

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Usually when I have such problems I test in a new private (incognito) window.

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue after clearing my cache yesterday.  Works for private browsing, but still needs a refresh otherwise.  I even had a co-worker test the feature with a completely different subdomain on a different computer: no thumbnail until she refreshed, too.

Here's a sample page you can test with: 'https://demo.mysmilecentral.com/public/show?link_code=demogirl2012' (click 'Order' under one of her images, then you'll see the Share button in the upper-right).

Does it work for you?

Comment: UPDATE: Just had the same problem with Private browsing, too.  Tried sharing a different image, but no thumbnail until I refreshed.

Comment: Sorry, that link should be demo.mysmilecentral.com/public/show?link_code=demogirl2012  - but I can't edit the comment to fix it.

Comment: Is your website demo.mysmilecentral.com? I tried to share your previous link on Facebook and everything is fine the thumbnail is correctly displayed as set in your meta tags.

Comment: Weird.  If it's the browser's cache that's the issue, I'm worried that everyone who's already visited our site (thousands of users) will see this problem unless they clear their cache, too.  I'll up-vote this answer again, and do some (mush needed, apparently) research on browser caching.  If needed, I'll follow up with a new question.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue, submitted a bug to Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/354887144656001
The first share issue appeared to be known bug to them, and there they suggest a workaround (submitting the new page to FB Debugger programmatically right after page creation).

Comment: Like you said in the FB bug report, the workaround offered by FB would require users to already be logged into FB. But hitting the OpenGraph API avoids that scenario.  I'm now posting to the OpenGraph API programatically, and all new shares are showing an image the first time.